# Как в библиотеке aiogram сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку появлялись другие кнопки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Вопрос в следующем, я пишу бота на aiogram, можно ли сделать так, что при нажатии на одну кнопку, появлявляются другие кнопки. Например пользователь нажимает на кнопку "настройки" и выпадают другие кнопки, которые уже являются параметрами настроек

Comment: Почему все новички выбирают не самую простую для понимания тему на начальном уровне? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Конечный_автомат

Comment: Отлови нажатие на кнопку и отправь сообщение с новыми кнопками

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, они её не выбирают, они в лоб просят решить задачу.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, ваш комментарий вообще неуместен, я давно занимаюсь алгоритмами и впервые сталкиваюсь с библиотекой aiogram. Я не знаю всех атрибутов и возможностей этой библиотеки, поэтому и спрашиваю у тех, кто знает. Я не хочу листать всю огромную документацию этой библиотеки, поскольку работаю с ботами крайне редко. Все, что я прошу, подсказать метод, с помощью которого можно решить  ою проблему

Comment: @Руслан, вас никто не принуждает читать всю документацию, просто такое ощущение, что вы и не пытались ничего искать. Первая ссылка гугл + 15 минут вашего времени, и все было бы готово

Comment: @Руслан мой ответ вообще никак не затрагивает какую либо библиотеку или какой либо ЯП, и относится к базовым знаниям которые вам понадобятся во всех подобных классах задач, безотносительно бот это или сайт. то что вам нужно - называется машина состояний(упрощенная версия конечного автомата), и не зная базы - у вас всегда будут вопросы как и зачем....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все взаимодействие бота Telegram с сервером происходит посредством GET/POST запросов. В случае с aiogramm за обарботку запросов отвечает Dispatcher `dp = Dispatcher(bot)` он предоставляет декоратор для твоих функций обработчиков

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['my_command']) <-- это эндпоинт /localhost/my_command
async def my_command(message: types.Message):
    reply = "Message"
    await message.answer(reply, reply_markup=get_keyboard())
```

В `reply_markup` функция `get_keyboard()` должна вернуть кнопки с нужными эндпоинтами для дальнейшей обработки через декоратор `@dp`